# Adding new features to selection list using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, editing, features, select

The code written by Joseph answering to the question [Features to stay selected by default in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186300/features-to-stay-selected-by-default-in-qgis)

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
# Use active layer

def select(featureAdded):
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([featureAdded])

layer.featureAdded.connect(select)
# Connect "featureAdded" event to "select" function
```

works, but as soon as another feature is created, a new selection is made, resulting in only the new feature been selected.

I would like to create many features that stay selected, and that are added to the features already selected. I am not good enough with scripting to create a working code.

Answer (score 3):

if you want add each new feature to selection , need add **QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection**

**Sample:**

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
def select(featureAdded):
    print(featureAdded)
    layer.selectByIds([featureAdded],QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)

layer.featureAdded.connect(select)
```

tested in QGIS 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `select()` function, you just need to replace :

```
layer.setSelectedFeatures([featureAdded])
```

with:

```
layer.select(featureAdded)
```

---

So the code would look like:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
def select(featureAdded):
    layer.select(featureAdded)

layer.featureAdded.connect(select)
```